Inferring parallel lines
I watched this video by Shree Nayar, where he discusses projection of parallel lines in 3D to 2D and the Vanishing Point effect.
It got me thinking about whether this can be analyzed from an image. Can we somehow tell from single image (not stereo camera), which lines are parallel in 3D? Naively, one might assume that all lines intersecting at a single point are parallel and that it is the Vanishsing point. However, I suspect that there is a specific point in the 3D space, in which every line in any orientation will also be mapped to such a supposed "vanishing point", thus making this guess wrong.
Is my analysis correct? Is there another way to infer this?

all lines are intersecting at a single point are parallel No. Draw two lines on a piece of paper that intersect at an angle of 30°: these lines intersect, but aren't parallel.

And every direction in which parallels could run has a point where they meet (if your projection works that way, which in general it doesn't do). You're confusing guidelines of post-medieval arts with physics here!

The lecturer explains that pretty well: "The location of that vanishing point depends on the orientation of these lines", but since lines can meet without being parallel, and since lines can be parallel and concentrate at any point in the picture, you mustn't invert the logical implication there!

As I suspected. Thanks. However this doesn't address the more general question: Is there some other way to extract parallel lines from an image? If no, you might want to turn your comment in to an answer so I can accept it.

I'd like to leave the writing of the answer up to you.
